# Redis set maxmemory per database

Tags: caching, redis

Is it possible to set `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy` per database in redis?

I've tried to switch to db `1` and set those properties

```
SELECT 1
CONFIG SET maxmemory 100mb
CONFIG SET maxmemory-policy allkeys-lfu
```

But it looks like they are being set per instance not a specific database

```
SELECT 2
CONFIG GET maxmemory

1) "maxmemory"
2) "104857600"


CONFIG GET maxmemory-policy

1) "maxmemory-policy"
2) "allkeys-lfu"
```

So, are there any ways to set those properties on a database level or should I use different instances / nodes?

Comment: "are there any ways to set those properties on a database level?" - NO. "should I use different instances / nodes?" - Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis DB is not completely independent, but logically independent.
I think you can think of it as a namespace.

The functionality you want will have to use another instance.